# Add/Edit Javascript program to calculate minimum, maximum, total and average of the array element

Tags: javascript, html, max, average, min

```
myArray = new Array(1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 10, 0)
document.write("<pre>")
document.write("myArray.toString()\t:\t\t")
document.write(myArray.toString()+"")
document.write("myArray.join('-')\t:\t\t")
document.write(myArray.join ("-")+"")
document.write("myArray.reverse()\t:\t\t")
document.write(myArray.reverse()+"")
document.write("myArray.sort()\t\t:\t\t")
document.write(myArray.sort()+"")
```

Comment: what are you looking for exactly, and why isn't your code doing what you think it is?

Comment: Better take a look at [Stackoverflow Academy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy)

Answer (score 4):

### Minimum and maximum

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, myArray);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, myArray);
```

### Total

```
var sum = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

### Average

Just divide `sum` by the number of array elements:

```
var average = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
})/myArray.length;
```

Comment: 5.6k rep; you should know not to answer help-vampire questions.