# find the average of both arrays, and then spit out the greater of the two

Tags: javascript

Whenever i run this it gives me, "first" instead of "second". Is my logic correct here? finding both avarages and then returning the greater? or what exactly do you see wrong with it.

```
var first = ([100, 80], [100, 100]);
function compare(a, b) {
  sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += first[i];
    avg1 = (sum/a.length);
  }

  sum2 = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    sum2 += first[i];
    avg2 = (sum2/b.length);
  }
  if (avg1 > avg2); {
    return ("first");
  }
  if (false) {
    return ("second");
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Is my logic correct here?"* If you don't get the result you expect, then your logic is probably not correct.

Comment: What are the arguments to the function? Why are you summing the same array in both loops?

Comment: What's the point of writing `var first = ( [100,80], [100,100]);`? The comma operator returns its second argument, so this is equivalent to `var first = ( [100,100]);`

Comment: Where is `len` defined? The code you posted seems to be **incomplete**, so we won't be able to run it.

Comment: Why is your iteration based on the lengths of `a` and `b`, but you're summing the elements of `first`?

Comment: `if (false)` will NEVER execute its body. That should probably be an `else` clause.

Comment: ya you all are givng me why its wrong but you arn't telling me how to fix it. Its obviously wrong if its not giving me an answer

Comment: Telling you what is wrong is the first step to fix it. Since we don't know what `a` and `b` are because you haven't shown how you call the function, there is little we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the average of the elements in `a` and `b`, you need to be summing those elements, not the elements of `first`.

Also, you had an extra `;` after `if (avg1 > avg2)`, which was creating an empty body for that conditional, so `return "first"` was being executed unconditionally.

```js
function compare(a,b) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        sum += a[i];
        var avg1 = (sum/a.length);
    }

    var sum2 = 0;
    for(i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
        sum2 += b[i];
        var avg2 = (sum2/b.length);
    }
    if (avg1 > avg2) {
        return "first";
    } else {
        return "second";
    }
}
alert(compare([80, 100], [100, 100]));
alert(compare([100, 150, 200], [50, 75, 100, 110]));
```

Comment: I know you mostly copied the code, but still: Don't forget local variables and the calculation of the averages can be moved outside of the loops.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that he left out some of the `var` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way of doing this...

First, take a look at [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174601/add-edit-javascript-program-to-calculate-minimun-maximum-total-and-average-of/25174679#25174679) for finding the average of an array of numbers in JavaScript.

```
var average = myArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
})/myArray.length;
```

You can do that for both your arrays and use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to return the greater average of the two. The whole function would look like this:

```
var greaterAverage = function (arr1, arr2) {
    return Math.max( arr1.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / arr1.length, arr2.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / arr2.length );
}
```

If you wanted to return the original array or something like "first", then you'd just compare the averages:

```
var greaterAverage = function (arr1, arr2) {
    var avg1 = arr1.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / arr1.length;

    var avg2 = arr2.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }) / arr2.length;

    if (avg1 < avg2) {
        return avg1; // or return "first";
    } else if (avg1 > avg2) {
        return avg2; // or return "second";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to go about it is to explicitly define the average.

The average of an array is the sum of its constituents divided by its length.  I have left this to throw an error on 0-length arrays because the average of an empty array is nonsense according to mathematics, but some people would guard for that and return zero instead.

To sum the constituents, reduce the array by adding members.

```js
var First  = [1,2,3],
    Second = [3,4,5];

function avg(A) {
    var Total = A.reduce( function(L,R) { return L+R; } );
    return Total / A.length;
}

window.alert( (avg(First) > avg(Second))? 'First' : 'Second' );
```

Answer (score 0):

first your `if else` syntax was wrong. `if else` syntax is

```
if (condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else { 
    block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Example

If the time is less than 20:00, create a "Good day" greeting, otherwise "Good evening":

```
if (time < 20) {
    greeting = "Good day";
} else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
}
```

output: Good day.

Check this jsfiddle link with the corrected code [Corrected code](http://jsfiddle.net/vn3L0avo/)