# JavaScript function that takes in two array of grades

Tags: javascript

This keeps on giving me  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'grades[2].length'). Help?

The question for this code is: write a JavaScript function that is called compare that takes in two array of grades and returns "first" if the first student has a higher average or "second" if the second student has a higher average.

```
function compare (grades)
{
  var sum1 = 0;
  var length1 = grades[1].length;
  for (i=0; i<grades[1].length; i++)
  {
    sum1 += grades[1];
    var avg1 = sum1/length1;
  }

  var sum2 = 0;
  var length2 = grades[2].length;
  for (var i=0; i<grades[2].length; i++)
  {
    sum2 += grades[2];
    var avg2 = sum2/length2;
  }

  if (avg1 > avg2)
  {
    return "first";
  }
  if (avg1 < avg2)
  {
    return "second";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you know, Javascript arrays begin with element 0, not element 1? Your for loops seem to know this, but the grades[1], grades[2] suggest not.

Comment: How is `compare()` called?

Comment: Is this a question in a introductory CS course? Was one of the previous question "calculateGPA" (letter to grade) or something like that?

Comment: How does the array of grades look? Please update your question and mark it homework if necessary

Comment: What happens if you console.log avg1 and avg2?

Comment: It should be grades[0] and grades[1].

Comment: what is grade?? Can you give the format of grade?

Comment: Can't answer without seeing how the compare method is called. anyway, javascript arrays are 0 indexed so take care of that. And your summation loops don't make sense at all, if grades[1] is an array, you add grades[1][i] in each iteration.

Comment: If `avg1` and `avg2` are equal your function will return `undefined`, you might want to add an `else` clause to handle that.

Comment: Similar assignment, different bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031063/find-the-average-of-both-arrays-and-then-spit-out-the-greater-of-the-two

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [1,2,3,4,7];

function compare(arr1 , arr2) {
    var aver1 = arr1.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) / arr1.length;
    var aver2 = arr2.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) / arr2.length;
    if(aver1 > aver2) {
        alert('First');
    } else if (aver1 < aver2) {
        alert('Second');
    }
}

compare(array1, array2);
```

**NOTE:** I am assuming that you are not using IE <= 8

[`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a built in function on Javascript Arrays.  If you click the link above to the documentation on MDN, you will see they give an example of how to sum an array similar to that used above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own function to Array instead of repeating yourself.

```
Array.prototype.avg = function(){
    // Note: "this" is a special JS variable, contains the array "calling" .avg()
    // So this.length is the length of the array, and this[0], this[1],... the data
    for(var i=0,l=this.length, sum=0; i<l; ++i) sum+=this[i]
    return sum/this.length
}

SallyPerfect = [100,100,100,100,95];  // She always gets good grades
LittleBobbyTables = [60,70,60,70,314.159]; // He plays too many games, but reads xkcd

alert("SallyPerfect avg is "+SallyPerfect.avg());
alert("LittleBobbyTables avg is "+LittleBobbyTables.avg());

var whoIsBetter = (SallyPerfect.avg()>LittleBobbyTables.avg())? "SallyPerfect": "LittleBobbyTables";
// you dont have to repeat yourself here, either, but it would require more code.

alert(whoIsBetter+" had the best average grade");
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bp9hvywe/

Of course, if this is a homework question, you should do as you are told and use some of this code (with a proper citation or attribution) to write a function that returns "first" or "second".

Comment: This is the exact same question in a homework of an introductory CS course I saw this weekend. So I believe this must be also a homework question for OP as well, and most probably OP won't understand what `Array.prototype` is.

Comment: I guess I disagree about pedagogy.  Among other things, this teaches printing out the averages.  If the OP had only tried printing the averages, it would have led the OP to realize that his code was only calculating one of the averages, not both. I suspect he is not watching the lecture, thus showing up here.  Maybe he is bored with the lecture because it takes so long to learn so little.  I'd rather he learn more and then learn to dumb it down to hand it in. If OTOH he truly doesn't care, then I'm writing for people who will.

Comment: I do pay attention in the lectures (@ Paul) but I missed two as I was dead sick. That's why I need help.

Comment: @PranavArya Hope you get better.  I think your code is close to being logically correct.  It is that matter of 0,1,2,3,... vs. 1,2,3,4,... for pulling the arrays of grades out of grades[].  However, you might want to reread the assignment again, because it says the input is *two arrays of grades*. Instead you have one array `grades` that itself contains two arrays `grades[0]` and `grades[1]`.  The function declaration for the assignment could be `function compare(gradesForPersonOne, gradesForPersonTwo){...}` and you would need to make some very small hopefully obvious changes.... Do you see?

Comment: @PranavArya Also, learn to start printing stuff out like crazy. It is the ONLY way you will discover what the code is doing.  The two print statements in javascript are `alert("pop up a message");` and `console.log("write on the debugging console, which is less obnoxious than alert but you have to hit control-shift-J in your browser to see the console");` Obviously remove the print statements before handing it in.